# SQL query which give unique entry only once in query table

Tags: sql

Basically I have 2 tables 1 OR 2 which is showed in below image.
i want to joint these 2 tables but the **value column** should be reflect only once in first entry only.

I have basic knowledge about SQL but please guide how can i get the required output as per the criteria which mention above.

[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: What if a table2 'A' row is missing for a code? Do you want value in the 'B' row instead?

Comment: @jarlh Sir, Basically I want only one entry towards code. doesn't matter it reflect in front of A,B,C or D or even if no value from one of these are  missing in data for specific code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `left join`:

```
select t2.*, t1.value
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t1.code = t2.code and t2.type = 'A';
```